# UIimage not loads on tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage

i am new to swift, currently making a personal app,

i am trying to load this image
[my image url](https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/saF3HtAduvrP9ytXDxSnQJP3oqx.jpg)

after that i used this code on my table view to load the image

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let url = posts[indexPath.row].message


        let url1 = URL(string: url!)
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url1!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
            MoviePoster.image = UIImage(data: data!)




            self.tableView.reloadData()
return cell

}
```

but instead of images, the screen looks like this
[screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJsiY.png)

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all  when implementing tableView you need to set **delegate and datasource** of your tableView in your **viewDiLoad**
like this.

```
yourTableView.datasource = self
yourTableView.delegate = self
```

before this you need to extend your tableView like this and i think you did already.

Now comes to the downloading part of your image. As you are new, the process by which you are downloading this image is not correct.

**why?**

1. you mentioned reloadData() in cellForRowAtIndexPath which is totally wrong.just check online answer for this.

Secondly your view might get in hang state because if your image is large then it will take time to show you image.So it might be that, you won't see anything or you view will not load either.

**How to resolve this?**

Download image using asynchronous way.And anything you want to download call it in **viewDidAppear**.

**Is there any library as a shortcut?**

Yes. Use SDWebImage. It's a great library. You don't have to think about all thing.It already did the job. All you have to do is to call. just like this.

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "yourdomainpathforImage"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Check out this from [here.](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: I can’t do that with 1 reputation

Comment: Done mate I know this don’t even worth what you gave me, but anyway I appreciate it so much:)